# Error in STL with two years of monthly data

Tags: r, stl, time-series

I am having sales data of an item for two years & for each month. The first column is row index [1:24], & the second column is the sales figure. I want to use `STL` to find `seasonal` & `trend` component. I tried;

```
ts_data<- ts(mydata[,-1],frequency = 12,start=c(2016,1))
ts_data
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
2016 1250  760 2590 7990 2070 6770 4760 4270 2550 6070 4580 2350
2017 1510 4140 2450 3010 1070 1230  850  490  170 1970  890 1871
```

I can see the data is now a timeseries object with proper timestamps. But,

```
ts.stl <- stl(ts_data,"periodic")
```

is giving me the well-known error,

```
Error in stl(ts_data, "periodic") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

I can see the data is periodic & spreading for two years. So, what is the reason behind it?

Surprisingly, the same data is working with `frequency=10` & I am able to generate the numbers. But having 10 frequency, it's going to 2018 which is wrong & completely unacceptable for my case.

```
ts_data<- ts(mydata[,-1],frequency = 10,start=c(2016,1))
ts.stl <- stl(ts_data,"periodic")
plot(ts.stl)
ts.stl
 Call:
 stl(x = ts_data, s.window = "periodic")

Components
Time Series:
Start = c(2016, 1) 
End = c(2018, 4) 
Frequency = 10 
          seasonal     trend   remainder
2016.0  -699.45750 2963.3599 -1013.90241
2016.1  -920.17520 3160.1418 -1479.96656
2016.2  -864.22434 3356.9236    97.30074
2016.3  2246.22241 3521.8163  2221.96126
2016.4  -810.00737 3686.7091  -806.70170
2016.5  1872.04426 3827.6781  1070.27765
2016.6   -50.90412 3968.6471   842.25700
2016.7  -174.47317 4057.6799   386.79324
2016.8 -1183.04223 4146.7128  -413.67053
2016.9   584.01391 3922.6366  1563.34950
2017.0  -699.45750 3698.5604  1580.89707
2017.1  -920.17520 3391.5549  -121.37975
2017.2  -864.22434 3084.5495  -710.32512
2017.3  2246.22241 2728.3775  -834.59993
2017.4  -810.00737 2372.2056   887.80179
2017.5  1872.04426 2129.8152  -991.85943
2017.6   -50.90412 1887.4248  -766.52066
2017.7  -174.47317 1704.6805  -300.20736
2017.8 -1183.04223 1521.9363   511.10594
2017.9   584.01391 1341.6322 -1435.64615
2018.0  -699.45750 1161.3282  -291.87070
2018.1  -920.17520  999.3977  1890.77746
2018.2  -864.22434  837.4673   916.75706
2018.3  2246.22241  689.0683 -1064.29067
```

How can I find the components using `frequency=12` in `STL`? Please guide me.

Comment: can you provide a `dput` of mydata?

Comment: > dput(mydata)


structure(list(Time = 1:24, Sales = c(1250L, 760L, 2590L, 7990L, 
2070L, 6770L, 4760L, 4270L, 2550L, 6070L, 4580L, 2350L, 1510L, 
4140L, 2450L, 3010L, 1070L, 1230L, 850L, 490L, 170L, 1970L, 890L, 
1871L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

Comment: Can you please guide what's the reason for the error?